# first-child seems to be not consistent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to select all `span` elements that are descendants of element `li:first-child` and element `a`.

Under *Menu 1*, my selector also selects *sub-menu 1.7 and 1.8*, but under *Menu 2* it works as expected. However, *Menu 1* and *Menu 2* have the same structure.

Thank you.
Andy.

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dedyandy/kmLxrgyn/1/

```css
.small-nav-dropdown-menu li:first-child a span {
  color: #000;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

span {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main-nav-dropdown-item-text {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.gif" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.gif" type="image/xIicon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/de6f7ac358.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="small-nav-dropdown-menu">      
  <ul style="background-color: rgb(36, 204, 151);">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span style="color: #fff">Menu 1</span>
      </a>
      <ul style="background-color: #00bc92;">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.1</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.6</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.7</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>
            <span class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.8</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span style="color: #fff">Menu 2</span>
      </a>
      <ul style="background-color: #00bc92;">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.1</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.5</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.6</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.7</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is an example selecting only submenu li:first-child http://jsfiddle.net/rxkbLaj9/19/

Comment: Just a tip: when asking a question, make sure to end with an actual question so that it's clearer what you need ;-)

Comment: Sorry about that. So my question is, I want to select sub-menu 1.1 and 2.1, but now it selects 1.1, 1.7, 1.8, and 2.1.

Comment: Don't worry, but make sure to include that in your original post in the form of a question. For instance, *Why does the selector also select sub-menu 1.7 and 1.8 when it's supposed to only select 1.1 and 2.1?* Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61420670/9060223) below, I'm sure you'll get it ;-)

Comment: Thank you. Next time I will make a better question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at it carefully. You have this selector:

```
.small-nav-dropdown-menu li:first-child
```

As another person has mentioned, this means that any `li` element that is targeted as a `:first-child` of **its own parent** will be selected. What does *its own parent* mean in your case? Your structure is the one that's causing a slightly unwanted behaviour. This diagram will make you understand why it's not working as expected.

```
div.small-nav-dropdown-menu
|-- ul
    |-- li // (Parent li) Aha! This is targeted with li:first-child because it is the first child of the above ul
    |   |-- ul
    |       |-- li -> a -> span
    |       |   // The above ^ span will be colored because the parent li 
    |       |   // (the one with "Aha!") has been targeted by the CSS
    |       |   // This li is also a target of li:first-child because it is the first child of the ul
    |       |-- li -> a // Not colored because the CSS doesn't detect span
    |       |   ... // A lot of li -> a
    |       |-- li -> a -> span
    |       |   // The above ^ span will be colored, again! This is because the parent li ("Aha!") is targeted
    |       |   // However, this time, the li wasn't targeted
    |       |-- li -> a -> span // Span will also be colored because the "Aha!" li is targeted!
    |
    |-- li // (Parent li) Okay, this is the second child, so it isn't targeted with li:first-child
        |-- ul
            |-- li -> a -> span
            |   // The above ^ span will be colored, but not because of the "Aha!" li
            |   // It is colored because the containing li is indeed the first child of the above ul
            |-- li -> a // Not colored because no span
            |   ... // A lot of li -> a
            |-- li -> a -> span
            |   // Not colored! Why? Containing li isn't first-child and the parent li, unlike the previous parent li,
            |   // isn't marked by li:first-child :O So this is why it isn't colored
            |-- li -> a -> span // Also not colored
```

So what's the solution? Change your selector or your HTML structure. Here's a working solution changing the CSS.

```css
.small-nav-dropdown-menu ul li li:first-child a span {
  color: #000;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

span {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main-nav-dropdown-item-text {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.gif" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.gif" type="image/xIicon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/de6f7ac358.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="small-nav-dropdown-menu">
    <ul style="background-color: rgb(36, 204, 151);">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span style="color: #fff">Menu 1</span>
        </a>
        <ul style="background-color: #00bc92;">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.1</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.4</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.5</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.6</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.7</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>
              <span class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.8</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span style="color: #fff">Menu 2</span>
        </a>
        <ul style="background-color: #00bc92;">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.1</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.4</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.5</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.6</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.7</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

However, I recommend giving a new class directly to the menu's ul like so and targeting that class instead.

```css
.a-new-class li:first-child a span {
  color: #000;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

span {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main-nav-dropdown-item-text {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.gif" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.gif" type="image/xIicon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/de6f7ac358.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="small-nav-dropdown-menu">
    <ul style="background-color: rgb(36, 204, 151);">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span style="color: #fff">Menu 1</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="a-new-class" style="background-color: #00bc92;">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.1</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.4</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.5</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.6</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.7</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>
              <span class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">1.8</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span style="color: #fff">Menu 2</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="a-new-class" style="background-color: #00bc92;">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.1</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.4</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.5</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.6</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="main-nav-dropdown-item-text">2.7</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much for the comprehensive explanation. I did not think that the second parent li from the first ul was already considered not the first li, and it was actually the parent of any a -> span below it.

Also thank you for the solution and the suggestion.

Comment: @Andy If my answer helped, consider accepting it and/or upvoting it ;-)

Comment: OK I have done it both. I seldom use stack overflow, so I didn't realize that there was a check symbol :-)

Answer (score 0):

`.small-nav-dropdown-menu li:first-child` means:

> Find `.small-nav-dropdown-menu` and get *any* `<li>` inside it, being a first child of *its own parent*.

So, it's understandable it works for your sub-menus as well. You should use a direct child operator:

```css
.small-nav-dropdown-menu > li:first-child
```

Comment: It works on sub-menu Menu 1 (it selects 1.1, 1.7 and 1.8), but it does not work on sub-menu Menu 2. Sub-menu 2.6 and 2.7 are not selected.

Comment: You know your HTML, just use `>` operator where necessary to achieve what you need.